# Update query including JOIN is taking 55 to 59 seconds to update the table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I've a table named **notification** and the table have almost 15000 rows data. I've two main things and that's are userid and isRead. I want to update the rows when the user click on **Mark all notifications read**. But when the user click on **Mark as Read** it takes 55 to 59 seconds to update the table or run the query. I'm updating with joins. Here is my query

```
UPDATE notification n
     , posts p 
   SET n.isRead = 1 
 Where (n.post_id = p.id and p.userid = $userid) 
    OR n.toUser = $userid 
   and n.isRead = 0
```

I don't know why it's taking too much time to update the table rows but when the query executes in that time i can't move to any other page while the query is in processing. Also I've created indexing on userid, isRead and p.userid in Post table but still the same problem. I don't know what to do.

I'm using this query through ajax in codeigniter but the response time is still same.

This is my table structure

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're really after something like this:

```
UPDATE notification n
  JOIN posts p 
    ON p.id = n.post_id 
   SET n.isRead = 1 
 WHERE :userid IN (n.toUser,p.userid)
```

For help with query optimization provide the EXPLAIN for the above, along with SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for both tables.

Comment: It's not working... I want to update all the rows according to userid in session. Where to put the user id in query. If i execute the query as it is that you sent to me it shows 0  rows effected.

Comment: I can't see your code, so can't really comment

Comment: I see 1 thing not mentioned.  :userid will require you to bind the user id value, it's only a place holder.  Or send the user id value in the execute command.

Answer (score 0):

When using `OR` in an `UPDATE`, it is usually faster to break it into multiple `UPDATEs`.

```
UPDATE notification n
     , posts p 
   SET n.isRead = 1 
 Where (n.post_id = p.id and p.userid = $userid) 

UPDATE notification n
     , posts p 
   SET n.isRead = 1 
 Where n.toUser = $userid 
   and n.isRead = 0
```

But caution...  `x OR y AND z` is the same as `x OR (y AND z)`, not `(x OR y) AND z`

Once you have broken it into two Updates, then check that you have the optimal indexes for each.

```
p:  INDEX(userId, id)
n:  INDEX(toUser, isRead)
n:  INDEX(postId)
```